# $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

is there an easy way to prove this: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \forall\varepsilon>0,\exists r\in \mathbb{Q}, |x-r|<\varepsilon $$
thank you

Comment: How do you define the $\mathbb R$?

Comment: For any number $x$ write $ x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x_k}{10^k} $. And then cut out enough terms for the difference to be less than $\epsilon$. But this is not really a proof, it depends on how you define $\mathbb{R}$ as the comment above states.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1. Prove first that, for each $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$, there exist $m$ and $n$ integers, with $n>0$, such that $a<m/n<b$. Then apply this to $a=x-\varepsilon$ and $b=x+\varepsilon$.

Hint 2. In order that $a<m/n<b$ you need $na<m<nb$. What's a condition on $nb-na$ that ensures the interval $(na,nb)$ contains an integer?